# Есть ли в асинхронном C# методы catch и then?

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность, catch

Извините за глупый вопрос, но меня интересует есть асинхронном C# методы `catch` и `then` ? Можно сделать такой код например ?

```
let calc=(a, b)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    let t=a+b;
     if(t==10){
         resolve(t);
     } else{
         reject(new Error(`No Number ${t}`));
      }
     }
    )}
    calc(7,8).then(re=>console.log(re)).
    catch(err=>console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: Зачем вам promises когда есть asyng await и try catch?

Comment: Покажите  пример на моем примере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример плохой, потому что здесь нет асинхронных операций, но синтаксически это может выглядеть так.

```csharp
Func<int, int, Task<int>> calc = async (a, b)
    => (a + b) is int t && t == 10 ? t : throw new Exception($"No, number is {t}");

try
{
    int sum = await calc(7, 8);
    // .then
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // .catch
    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
No, number is 15
```

---

Более читабельный код асинхронного метода

```cs
private async Task<int> Calc(int a, int b)
{
   int t = a + b;
   if (t == 10) return t;
   throw new Exception($"No, number is {t}");
}
```

Comment: Пока выёживался на телефоне ответ скинул :)))

Comment: => (a + b) is int t && t == 10 ? t : throw new Exception($"No, number is {t}"); извините я это код хотел переделать на обычный if так просто код более читабельный

Comment: @Грустьжизни переписал

Comment: Спасибо вам) что услышали меня )

Answer (score 0):

Так ответ на ваш вопрос.

```
// Создаём таск
var task = new Task<StateObject>(() => { /* action */ });

// На случай ошибки 
task.ContinueWith(t => { /* error handling */ }, context, 
TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

// Успешный случай 
task.ContinueWith(t => { /* on success */ }, context, 
TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
// Пуск
task.Start();
```

Но async await по современнее.

```
try {
  var res = await calc(a,b);
  Console.WriteLine(res);
} catch(Exception ex)
{
 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Покажите пример только, с моим примером на async await

Comment: С `TaskContinuationOptions` надо быть осторожным, особенно при комбинации с `await`, потому что если условие продолжения не выполняется, будет брошено исключение `TaskCancelledException`, что само по себе - логичный, но очень неприятный побочный эффект.